# How to have an entity inherit from another base entity and map to db using TPC with EF 4.2?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4, table-per-type, entity-framework-4.2

Say I have an entity model aggregate for Activity, like so:

```
public class Activity : Entity
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActivityTag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityTag : Entity
{
    public int ActivityPersonId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Forget about the relation between Activity and Person, but note the 1..* relation between Activity and ActivityTag. The fluent mapping looks more or less like this:

```
public class ActivityOrm : EntityTypeConfiguration<Activity>
{
    public ActivityOrm()
    {
        ToTable("Activity", "Activities");
        HasKey(p => new { p.PersonId, p.Number });
        HasRequired(d => d.Person)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        HasMany(p => p.Tags)
            .WithRequired(d => d.Activity)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.ActivityPersonId, d.ActivityNumber })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        Property(p => p.Content).HasColumnType("ntext");
    }
}

public class ActivityTagOrm : EntityTypeConfiguration<ActivityTag>
{
    public ActivityTagOrm()
    {
        ToTable("ActivityTag", "Activities");
        HasKey(p => new { p.ActivityPersonId, p.ActivityNumber, p.Number });
        Property(p => p.Text).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(500);
    }
}
```

Given this, I want to introduce a new collection property to the `Activity` entity:

```
public ICollection<DraftedTag> DraftedTags { get; set; }
```

The `DraftedTag` entity should have the same exact properties and primary key as `ActivityTag`. The only thing that should be different is the table it is mapped to. I tried creating a class that derived from ActivityTag, like so:

```
public class DraftedTag : ActivityTag
{
}

public class DraftedTagOrm : EntityTypeConfiguration<DraftedTag>
{
    public DraftedTagOrm()
    {
        Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("DraftedTag", "Activities");
        });
        HasKey(p => new { p.ActivityPersonId, p.ActivityNumber, p.Number });

    }
}
```

The DraftedTagOrm has been added to the modelBuilder.Configurations collection, but without even adding the foreign key association to Activity, I get the following exception:

> The property 'ActivityPersonId' is not a declared property on type
>   'DraftedTag'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid
>   primitive property.

When I completely duplicate the code from the ActivityTag class and the ActivityTagOrm constructor into the respective DraftTag class / configuration constructor, then it works as expected -- I get two different tables with identical schemas, but different names. However each time I want to make a change to the ActivityTag class, I must make a corresponding change in the DraftTag class.

Is it possible to make this code DRYer by having DraftTag extend ActivityTag? If so, what would the EntityTypeConfiguration look like for DraftTag?

Comment: The key is already defined in your parent `ActivitTag` mapping so you should not define it again in derived mapping. The key must be same. What happens if you remove key mapping from `DraftedTag`?

Comment: It then ends up with 2 relationships to Activity. One inherited by the parent, and another defined for the DraftedTag.

Comment: But that is correct - it is what TPC demands. Database doesn't understand inheritance. If you want to have TPC hierarchy related to another table the relation must be created with every table in TPC hierarchy.

Comment: So then, if I want Activity to have 2 separate collections -- 1 of ActivityTag and another of DraftedTag -- then the correct way to implement this is to make one *Tag entity extend the other?